# Feedback that a slow php script is working?

Tags: php

Running a PHP script that is doing a huge mysql query plus some crunching on the results. Because of this the script takes a long time to execute and may appear to be not working to the user.

Is there a way to provide feedback to the user that the script is running? 
Perhaps way to print to the browser with each loop - indicating what record it's on... kind of a "live output buffer" or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `flush()`. https://www.php.net/flush

You could also have a main page, that uses Javascript/jQuery to request the work page. Then, Javascript could show a nice little loader box telling you the the page is still doing stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Do the request in an iframe. That way the user sees a page while the results are still being loaded in the frame. Ajax would work as well.

Comment: Please use ajax not an iframe :)

Comment: that's fine if you want to force your users to have JS enabled. That isn't always a good idea. Also ajax is more difficult to implement.